# How to make a condition in php - display one or another date?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, codeigniter

How to make a condition in this construction - display one or another date?

```
<?php foreach ($items as $k => $v): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $v['number'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $v['date_from'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $v['date_till'] ?></td> 
                <td><?= $v['dealer_title'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $v['producer_title'] ?><?= $v['sys_create'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo nl2br($v['producer_address']); ?><?php echo nl2br($v['sys_create_address']); ?></td>
                <td><?= nl2br($v['offers_title']) ?><?= nl2br($v['sfera']) ?></td>
                <td><?= $v['status'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The database has 2 tables: **date_till** and **date_till2**.
It is necessary that, if necessary, the date is displayed either from **date_till** or **date_till2**.
At the moment, if there is no data in the date_till table, an incorrect date is displayed: **30.11.-0001**.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Th solution would be to use the ternary operator within the PHP code:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $k => $v): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $v['number'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $v['date_from'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $v['date_till'] ? $v['date_till'] : $v['date_till2'] ?></td> 
        <td><?= $v['dealer_title'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $v['producer_title'] ?><?= $v['sys_create'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo nl2br($v['producer_address']); ?><?php echo nl2br($v['sys_create_address']); ?></td>
        <td><?= nl2br($v['offers_title']) ?><?= nl2br($v['sfera']) ?></td>
        <td><?= $v['status'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

For this to work according to your date format, you need to modify the model file:

```
if (isset($_POST['date_till']) && $_POST['date_till']) {
    $dateTill = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date_till']));
    $data['date_till'] = ($dateTill != '0000-00-00') ? $dateTill : NULL;
}
```

Comment: Apparently, i still need to correctly query the database, in the model file there is such a condition:

if (isset($_POST['date_till']) && $_POST['date_till']) {
            $data['date_till'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date_till']));
        }

When saving a date to the database, if it is written in the date_till or date_till2 field, then in one of them this value appears 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Can you please tell me how to do the correct condition here too?
Sorry, i'm new to php and mysql )

Comment: Gotcha, I edited my answer :)

Comment: Still doesn't work (

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more readable example with additional testing and secure handling (untested):

```php
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    // If date_till is empty, set to date_till2;
    if ( empty( $item['date_till'] ) ) {
        $item['date_till'] = $item['date_till2'];
    }

    // If date_till is still empty, then we've no date: set to "Unknown".
    if ( empty( $item['date_till'] ) ) {
        $item['date_till'] = 'Unknown';
    }

    echo '<tr>';

    printf( '<td>%s</td>', esc_html( $item['number'] ) );
    printf( '<td>%s</td>', esc_html( $item['date_from'] ) );
    printf( '<td>%s</td>', esc_html( $item['date_till'] ) );
    printf( '<td>%s</td>', esc_html( $item['dealer_title'] ) );

    printf( 
        '<td>%s%s</td>', 
        esc_html( $item['producer_title'] ), 
        esc_html( $item['sys_create'] ) 
    );

    printf( 
        '<td>%s%s</td>', 
        nl2br( esc_html( $item['producer_address'] ) ), 
        nl2br( esc_html( $item['sys_create_address'] ) ) 
    );

    printf(
        '<td>%s%s</td>',
        nl2br( esc_html( $item['offers_title'] ) ),
        nl2br( esc_html( $item['sfera'] ) )
    );

    printf( '<td>%s</td>', esc_html( $item['status'] ) );

    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Ternary operators are valuable for their conciseness, which in some cases is more readable, but in most cases reduces readability.